# Enabling autoplay with Owl carousel after scrolling to specific point

Tags: jquery, scroll, owl-carousel

I am using the [Owl Carousel plugin](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/), and everything works fine, apart from one thing. I want to **enable** the carousel autoplaying when I scroll down the page.

The problem is, when I scroll down, the carousel starts autoplaying, or tries to...

[It's extremely buggy](http://tinyurl.com/jd7r7cw).

```
jQuery('#consultants').owlCarousel({
        /* autoPlay: false, */
        pagination: false,
        navigation: true,

        itemsCustom : [
            [0, 1],
            [320, 2],
            [450, 3],
            [600, 4],
            [750, 6],
            [1100, 6]
        ],
    });
```

Autoplay when user scrolls 700 pixel down the page:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() 
{
    var y_scroll_pos = window.pageYOffset;
    var scroll_pos_test = 700;             

    if(y_scroll_pos > scroll_pos_test) 
    {
        var owl = jQuery("#specialist-consultants-list");
        owl.trigger('owl.play');

        console.log('Scroll point reached');
    }
});
```

Any clue as to why it behaves like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can fine answer [here](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/#customizing) on the part of "5. Owl Data methods". but for take it short you can use this codes

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  jQuery("#owl-example").owlCarousel({autoPlay : true});
  var owl = jQuery("#owl-example").data('owlCarousel');
  owl.stop();
  jQuery(window).scroll(function() 
  {
      var y_scroll_pos = window.pageYOffset;
      var scroll_pos_test = 700;             

      if(y_scroll_pos > scroll_pos_test) 
      {
          owl.play()
      }
  });
});
```

and if you need to owlCarousel slide immediately after user scroll to "700px" and then every slide spend 5 seconds delay

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var owl_event = jQuery("#owl-example");
  owl_event.owlCarousel({autoPlay : true,slideSpeed : 5000});
  var owl = jQuery("#owl-example").data('owlCarousel');
  owl.stop();
  jQuery(window).scroll(function() 
  {
      var y_scroll_pos = window.pageYOffset;
      var scroll_pos_test = 700;             

      if(y_scroll_pos > scroll_pos_test && owl.apStatus != "play") 
      {
          owl.play();
          owl_event.trigger('owl.next');
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: Perfect. Would you also know how I can set the autoplay to fire straight away AND then slide every 5 seconds?

It seems these two functions are related :(

Comment: @KeithDonegan sorry i don't get you question, you need to autoplay fire immediately after user scroll to 700px, and after starting slideshow, every slide spend 5 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set flag that indicates that carousel is already triggered. In other case I think you are triggering carousel autoplay hundred of times when you scroll.
It could be sth like this:

```
var scrolled = false;
jQuery(window).scroll(function() 
{
    var y_scroll_pos = window.pageYOffset;
    var scroll_pos_test = 700;             

    if(y_scroll_pos > scroll_pos_test && !scrolled) 
    {
        scrolled = true;
        var owl = jQuery("#specialist-consultants-list");
        owl.trigger('owl.play');

        console.log('Scroll point reached');
    }
});
```

Or also after triggering first time you can just disable this scroll event handler on window.

However I cannot confirm if that works on 100% as I don't have jsfiddle with your complete code.